# Which ways do I have to get ethereum node?

Tags: blockchain, cpp-ethereum

I want to know which ways I could get ethereum node besides setting up one on my own server.
I need node in order for my application to work with ethereum blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a public node provider like  [infura](https://infura.io/)